# Why malloc allocates more memory than neeed?

Tags: linux, c, posix

While working with `malloc()` and `sbrk()` I found that the `malloc()` function always allocates minimum of `135168 bytes` even if `1 byte` is requested. Why `malloc()` allocates so much memory ? I can allocate `4 kB` size of memory. Assuming page block size is `4 kB`.

Shouldn't it allocate the `128 * 1024 =  131072 bytes` instead of `135168 bytes` as the threshold is `128 kB` after which it uses `mmap()` ?

I am very confused. I don't have very in-dept knowledge of internal working of `malloc()`.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: How did you measure how much `malloc()` allocated?

Comment: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/tree/master/malloc

Comment: When you say "always" what happens if you allocate 1 byte on a loop? If you call malloc 1000 times does it allocate 1000 * 135168?  I would expect memory to be allocated in largish blocks but I would also expect those blocks to be reused between seperate callls.

Answer (score 2):

This is purely an optimisation. The guess is that, if you use malloc() once, you will use it several more times. So there is a single initial system call to extend process space (which affects the virtual address mappings and is relatively expensive).

The amount you requested is taken from that area and its address is returned from your malloc() call. The remainder is added to the free list (which is initially empty).

If you are using any stdio (e.g. to print the initial value of sbrk() ) then stdio will have already made the first malloc() for the buffer used by the FILE* for stdout: your own malloc(1) gets memory from the free list.

mmap() is used only for large single allocations. Small allocations use a free list area which can be readily subdivided.